# Roots of $x^3 - 2$ in $\mathbb F_7[X]/\langle X^3 - 2 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

> Let $F = \frac{\mathbb F_7[X]}{\langle X^3 - 2 \rangle}$. Let $\alpha$ denotes the image of $X$ in $F$. Show that $\alpha, 2\alpha$ and $4\alpha$ are the roots of $X^3 - 2$.

What is not cleared to me is that under what map does $X$ goes to $\alpha$? And from where? Also, I have proven that if $\alpha$ is a root of some irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ inside $\mathbb F_p[X]$, then  $\alpha, \alpha^p, \alpha^{p^2}, ..., \alpha^{p^{d-1}}$ are roots of that irreducible polynomial. But after that I'm stuck.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are the possibilities $\alpha$ can be? It might help to think of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_7^\times$ not as the numbers 1 to 6 but instead as 6th roots of unity.

Comment: "Under what map does $X$ go to $\alpha$?"  Under the quotient map $\mathbb{F}_7[X] \to F = \mathbb{F}_7[X] / \langle X^3 - 2 \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what you proved, the roots are $\alpha, \alpha^7$ and $\alpha^{49}$.  (Do you know why these are all the roots?)

Remember as $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3-2$ that tells us $\alpha^3=2$. Thus $\alpha^7=\alpha^6\alpha=2^2\alpha=4\alpha$. Similarly, it can be shown that $\alpha^{49}=2\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple: as in all fields, if you have a cube root $\alpha$ of an element, all cube roots in that field are obtained multiplying $\alpha$ by the cube roots of unity.
It happens that in $\mathbf F_7$, the cube roots of unity are $1,2$ and $4$.